# PUT request using Django serializer

Tags: django, postgresql, django-rest-framework, serialization

I have an architecture in a way that when user registers, his/her settings are initialized. So we need GET and PUT to get or update the settings respectively on settings API.

I am using model serializers of django rest framework for storing and getting the settings. It works well in giving response but it doesn't save that to models.

**`serializers.py`**

```
class UserSettingsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = UserSettings
        fields = ('group_notifications', 'updates', 'goal_remind_me', 
                  'goal_days', 'goal_time_interval', 'user')
```

**`models.py`**

```
class UserSettings(models.Model):

class Meta:
    db_table = 'user_settings'

user = models.ForeignKey('User')
group_notifications = models.BooleanField(default=True)
updates = models.BooleanField(default=False)
goal_remind_me = models.BooleanField(default=False)
goal_days = ListField()
goal_time_interval = models.IntegerField(null=True)
```

**`views.py`**

```
def settings(request, pk):
    if request.method == 'PUT':
        request.data['user'] = user.id

        serializer = UserSettingsSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            serializer_dict = serializer.data
            serializer_dict["message"] = "Settings updated successfully."
            return Response(serializer_dict, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        else:
            return Response(serializer.errors,
                            status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

I get response as expected but it's not storing data in `user_settings` table and I am using PostgreSql.

Comment: The `serializer.save()` returns an instance. Try `instance = serializer.save()` and check what you get in your instance.

Comment: You're trying to do an update? It's doing a create here.

Comment: Yup it's doing a create while I just want one record per user

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order for a ModelSerializer to preform an update, you need to pass in the instance that you want updated to the constructor.

```
def settings(request, pk):
    # query for the UserSettings object
    instance = get_object_or_404(UserSettings.objects.all(), pk=pk)

    if request.method == 'PUT':
        request.data['user'] = user.id

        # pass in the instance we want to update
        serializer = UserSettingsSerializer(instance, data=request.data)

        # validate and update
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            serializer_dict = serializer.data
            serializer_dict["message"] = "Settings updated successfully."
            return Response(serializer_dict, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        else:
            return Response(serializer.errors,
                            status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: Oh Yes! Thanks. I was trying to pass the user instance which is foreign key.